# Simple Entity Framework Navigation error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I'm a newbie in ASP.NET MVC4. This is my problem:

I have two tables as follow:

```
`Users(Username, Password, Email, RoleId)`
```

and

```
`Roles(Id, Name)`
```

Which `Users.RoleId` is foreign key references to `Roles.Id`

This is my classes:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key, Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [StringLength(32), Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [StringLength(70), Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}

[Table("Roles")]
public class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Database : DbContext
{
    public Database()
        : base("WebstoreDbConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I can select all users in my DB with:

```
using (var db = new Database())
{
    ViewBag.Users = db.Users.ToList();
}
```

and show it in view:

```
@foreach(var user in ViewBag.Users) {
    <p>@user.Username | @user.Password</p>
}
```

but statement: `@user.Role.Name` give me an error:

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

What's cause the problem and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above suggestion is good. However, the error message means that you have closed the connection when you try to access the Role Property from the user. It should work because you declared it as "virtual", which means that you want the lazy loading.

```
using (var db = new Database())
{
    ViewBag.Users = db.Users.ToList();
}
```

When you try to use "using" to wrap the db connection, you have disposed the connection after the statement. If you could close the connection later, you shouldn't need the Include here.

Comment: Maybe you should add that technically this is possible but that it's not a generally recommended way.

Comment: Normally, you will associate context with http request, so you will close the db context at the end of http request, and the lazy loading will work in this situation. Personally, I am not a big fan of lazy loading

Answer (score 1):

try like this :

```
using (var db = new Database())
{
    ViewBag.Users = db.Users.Include("Role").ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, what's the magic behind scene? So, if I want to get all users in a role, I have to do `db.Roles.Include("Users").Where(...)`? Is there some way to remove `Include`?

Comment: EF create the most simple query it can. if you dont need role it dont join secondary table, if you want role it create an inner join but you need to say it with Include.